# Interchanging rows in a matrix more than once before determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I know that people have covered the fact that changing rows will make the determinant negative, and other row operations don't affect the result, but what about interchanging the rows more than once? Does it convert it back to positive again?

Comment: Consider each interchange one by one. How does each change the determinant?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't "make the determinant negative", it changes $D$ to $-D$.
That happens each time you interchange two rows.  So interchange them an odd number of times, you change $D$ to $-D$; interchange an even number of time, you leave the determinant unchanged.